# Got red screen of death after installing Centos6.6 on HP Proliant using cobbler

Tags: centos

I'm trying to install CentOS 6.6 on a HP server using Cobbler 2.6.3. The installation process seems to be fine, but after rebooting, I get a red screen of death when the system tries to load the SO. I tried to install the same SO using a DVD and it worked fine; and then I try to move the hard disks with the SO cobblered on them to another server and this server booted right as well. Then, on the new server, I try to use cobbler to reinstall the SO and, again, I got the red screen.

I don't know what else I can do or try, any suggestion will be welcomed. Currently, I'm using the sample.ks file to discard errors on the kickstart template

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hope you find here the answer! ;)